# Custom tag libraries in JSP with Java EE 7

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, custom-tags

I am having a difficult time to find the right way to implement my custom tags in JSP with Java EE 7. I could see the web.xml 'taglig' elements have been obsoleted and Java EE 7 documentation talks just about JSF custom tags implementation but not JSPs.Unfortunately, I don't have a chance to move to JSF.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be more specific on your custom tag use case.
The easiest way of defining a custom tag is defining .tag file (type of JSP with extension .tag) and place it into {yourapp}/WEB-INF/tags/{dir}

e.g.

I have a custom.tag in WEB-INF/tags/custom

```
<%@attribute name="greetName" type="java.lang.String"%>
<div>Hello, ${greetName }</div>
```

In my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/custom" prefix="ctm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP in EE7</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Before tag</div>
        <ctm:custom greetName="John"></ctm:custom>
        <div>After tag</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: simple custom tag]

There's also way to define tag using java code:
1. Create a .tld file in WEB-INF
2. Extending [BodyTagSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTagSupport.html) or [SimpleTagSupport](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jspapi/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html) class

.tag file is great for reusing some fragment of html and extend the *TagSupport classes if you need more flexibility.